# Verilog data types

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I am studying verilog as part of my university course however my module lecturer left so I was hoping for some help here,

An example we have been given for a parametric n-bit gray to binary code converter, as follows:

```
module bin_n_gray #(parameter n=4) (input [n-1 : 0] gray, output [n-1 : 0] bin);

    integer i;
    always @ (*)
        for(i = 0; i < n; i = i+1)
            bin[i] = ^(gray >> i);

endmodule
```

My question:

As the `bin[i]` variable is on the left hand side of an assignment statement within an `@ always` block shouldn't this variable be declared as `output reg [n-1 : 0] bin`?

As I thought that a variable on the left hand side of an assignment statement of a process block i.e `always` / `initial` should be declared as a `reg` datatype?

Comment: Yes, I believe, that should be of reg type, as it is not continuously assigned, and may need to retain it's value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As the bin[i] variable is on the left hand side of an assignment statement within an '@ always' block shouldn't this variable be declared as 'output reg [n-1 : 0] bin?

Yes, it should require the `reg` as you say, at least according to Xilinx XST. The code as given in your question errs when synthesizing using that tool (and is missing an unrelated semicolon).

First let's begin by understanding what a procedural block in Verilog is, exactly (with the assumption that we're using Verilog to develop hardware, such as an FPGA design). Procedural blocks are `always` blocks (of two types, combinational and sequential) as well as few other types of blocks we won't cover here. The first thing to know is that *in a procedural block, the only assignments allowed are those that have a `reg` on the left hand side.*

This doesn't necessarily mean that a physical register/flipflop will be created. In this case, one will not be. The reason is the declaration of the block as `always @ (*)`. This declaration means that the process is combinational (i.e. not sequential, not having any internal state or clock signal). As a result, no physical flip-flops are created.

Alternatively, you can have a procedural block declared as `always @ (posedge some_clock_signal)`. This means that sequential logic is created, and physical flip-flops (or other means of storage such as the distributed memory in FPGA lookup tables) may be used. The takeaway is that you're still declaring as `reg` there, but now you're actually creating registers.

There is one case where you  use *`wire`* (or `output`), which is by continuous assignment (for example, `assign a = b & c`), which falls outside a procedural block. In this example, I'm using `generate` to do the same thing as the loop in your original code:

```
module bin_n_gray #(parameter n=4) (input [n-1 : 0] gray, output [n-1 : 0] bin);
   genvar i;
   generate
      for (i=0; i < n; i=i+1) 
      begin: graydecoder // arbitrary label needed by generate syntax
         assign bin[i] = ^(gray >> i);
      end
   endgenerate
endmodule
```

Comment: Im confused! could you explain it in a simplified manner as i'm only just learning this stuff!

Comment: @AndyWest I'll be glad to, but I unfortunately cannot at this moment. Would it be a problem if I updated my answer in a half-hour to hour or so?

Comment: The first part of your answer seems as if youre saying yes it should be declared as reg but the second part seems like your saying wire is fine,

Comment: @AndyWest Noted, I'll clarify that wording once I get the chance.

Comment: @AndyWest You were right (and I didn't notice). It does need to be a `reg`, at least according to my FPGA tools (Xilinx ISE/XST). I'll write an explanation in an answer edit now.

Comment: @AndyWest Updated. Please let me know if I should clarify anything further.

Comment: Agreed, the code as posted is illegal because you are never allowed to make procedural assignments to wires. I think  @hexafraction was just trying to explain that the synthesis POV, the `reg` keyword does not add anything to the description because a synthesis tool actually implements that `always` description more like the generate block with concurrent continuous assignments. But from the Verilog LRM's POV, the code is illegal. It's just like having code like `i = idontcare *0;` without ever declaring `idontcare` and saying that shouldn't be a problem because I'm multiplying it by 0.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for the clarification. I have also updated the code to include the missing semicolon you mentioned for future readers convenience